# How to plot 2 radarplots in a shiny tab in one polar axis

Tags: r, shiny, chart.js, axis, tabpanel

[image: radar plots in one shiny tab]

Hello,
I would like to plot 2 radars in the same axis in my shiny tab.
The first radar plot takes input from the checkbox and the second one from the selectInput.Both datasets displayed have the same length and the same variables.
I am thinking that is a matter of tabsetpanel parameter.
Pls help.

Here is my ui.R

```
tabPanel("RCD + ACD Plots", chartJSRadarOutput("radar",width = "900%", height = "300%"),
chartJSRadarOutput("radar2",width = "900%", height = "300%" )),
```

Comment: What is the problem? Does your proposed solution not work? If not what is the error? And did you try to create a minimal example that does this?

Comment: I am trying to put these 2 plots above in the same graph area.One plot above the other and not separately.